# Listen for commands within a command discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, discord.js, event-handling

I am building a discord bot using slash commands with discord.js V14.7.1.
I have a command that sets up a listener for images from the command user. I want this command to stop collecting images when the same command is used again by the command user so only one instance of it is active at a time.

In discord.js, I have my command files separate from my command handler which I basically copied from the discord.js guide and am running commands via `command.execute()`. Currently, I am passing in the client as an argument for #execute and then within the commands separate file I am using the following code to shut down the image collector.

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async i => {
        if (!i.isChatInputCommand()) return;
        const command = client.commands.get(i.commandName);
        const isSameCommand = command.data.name == interaction.commandName;
        const isSameUser = i.user.id == interaction.user.id;

        if (isSameCommand && isSameUser) {
          imageCollector.stop();
        }
      });
```

After several people use the command I get the following warning: `(node:20760) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 22 interactionCreate listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`. I think I can tell why this is occurring and presume it to be a problem if the bot is left running for a very long time, but I don't know how else to solve the problem or clean up the listeners.

Comment: Create a variables outside any command and modify/check them every time the command is used. For example, you could use global variables for the collectors and another to control the collectors

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to not create a listener for every user.
Assuming the users are sending images in normal messages, you can put this logic in the `messageCreate` event listener.

```
let usersToCollect = [] //The slash command pushes and removes images to this array, you can use database later

client.on('messageCreate', async function (message) {
  if (!message.attachements) return // Your logic for determining if its an image here 
  if (usersToCollect.includes(message.author.id) {
    // save image
  }
}
```